# Network blocking my router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I've just moved in a new office building and I'm trying to set up a router so that I can connect my printer, Chromecast and such on my own network. The router worked fine for a day or two, then I couldn't connect to it via Wifi. The only way I can access to the admin console is via direct ethernet connection.

My guess was that the router was interfering with the network config, but I can't seem to find what is causing the issue. I've tried using dynamic IP, manually entering the DNS I get from the ethernet connection, MAC cloning, turning off DCHP, but the bug remains.

It looks like the network is set up using Cisco Meraki.

Is there something I haven't done yet that could fix the issue without having to check with the network engineers?

Comment: What is the operating system on the system from which you are trying to establish a Wifi connection to your router? Does that system see the [SSID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_%28802.11_network%29) of the wireless network provided by your router?

Comment: Cisco Meraki is a cloud based managed network service... Maybe you should talk to your ISP or manager of the network for your building.

Comment: Are you an employee connecting this router to the company network in order to access your home network/resources?

Answer (score 0):

Some enterprise APs let the admin set them to block *[deauth]* unauthorised WiFi networks, to prevent malicious fake networks, it is possible this explains the WiFi stopping working while Ethernet still works.

If this is the case, to fix this you would need to talk to whoever controls the APs affecting your network.

[Reference](https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/Monitoring_and_Reporting/Air_Marshal_Containment)